# Constrained matrices

Tags: r, constraints, permutation

I need to create all the possible matrix of dimension 5 (5x5), where all elements are integers from 0 to 100 and its sum is 100.

I'm not sure how to do it, or how to start... Any suggestion?

Despite I program in R, I'm looking for an idea of how to do it. Pseucode is fine.

My firs approach was getting all the permutations of 100 elements 25 times (one for each element in the matrix) and then take only those that sum 100. But that is 100^25 permutations... no way to do it in this by this approach.

I will thanks any idea and/or help!

Comment: I didn't notice *all possible matrices* part initially before I answer (I deleted it). I think even the number of all possible matrices would be huge!

Comment: Indeed it is... I guess I need to find another approach. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP is looking for all integer partitions of the number 100 of maximal length of 25.  The package `partitions` is equipped with a function exactly for this purpose called `restrictedparts`. E.g.:

```
library(partitions)
## all integer partitions of 10 of maximal length = 4
restrictedparts(10, 4)                                               
[1,] 10 9 8 7 6 5 8 7 6 5 6 5 4 4 7 6 5 4 5 4 3 4 3
[2,]  0 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 1 2 3 4 2 3 3 2 3
[3,]  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 2
[4,]  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

Once all of the them have been generated, simply create a 5x5 matrix of each combinations (`restrictedparts` doesn't differentiate between `0 0 3` and `0 3 0`). The only problem is that there are so many possible combinations (`partitions::R(25, 100, TRUE) = 139620591`) the function throws an error when you call `restrictedparts(100, 25)`.

```
test <- restrictedparts(100, 25)
```

> Error in restrictedparts(100, 25) : NAs in foreign function call (arg 3)
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In restrictedparts(100, 25) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Since we can't generate them all via `restrictedparts`, we can generate them individually using `firstrestrictedpart` along with `nextrestrictedpart` like so:

```
funPartition <- function(n) {
    p <- firstrestrictedpart(100, 25)
    mat <- matrix(nrow = 25, ncol = n)
    mat[,1] <- p
    for (i in 2:n) {
        p <- nextrestrictedpart(p)
        mat[,i] <- p
    }
    mat
}

head(funPartition(5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  100   99   98   97   96
[2,]    0    1    2    3    4
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

The only problem with this is that it isn't as efficient.

**Enter RcppAlgos**

There is a faster way using the package `RcppAlgos`(which I am the author of).

```
library(RcppAlgos)
combs <- comboGeneral(0:100,25,TRUE,"sum","==",100,rowCap=10^5)
matrixCombs <- lapply(1:nrow(combs), function(x) matrix(combs[x,], nrow = 5, ncol = 5))

matrixCombs[1:3]
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0  100

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0   99

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    2
[5,]    0    0    0    0   98
```

If you really want permutations, no problem, just call `permuteGeneral`:

```
perms <- permuteGeneral(0:100,25,TRUE,"sum","==",100,rowCap=10^5)
matrixPerms <- lapply(1:nrow(perms), function(x) matrix(perms[x,], nrow = 5, ncol = 5))

matrixPerms[1:3]
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0  100

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0  100
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0  100
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

It is super fast as well. Let `norm100Master` be a wrapper of `norm100` along with `lapply(rep(5, runs), norm100)`.

```
funRcppAlgos <- function(myCap) {
    perms <- permuteGeneral(0:100,25,TRUE,"sum","==",100,rowCap=myCap)
    lapply(1:myCap, function(x) matrix(perms[x,], nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
}

runs <- 5000
microbenchmark(norm100Master(runs), funRcppAlgos(runs))
Unit: milliseconds
               expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
norm100Master(runs) 50.930848 56.413103 65.00415 57.341665 64.242075 125.5940   100
 funRcppAlgos(runs)  8.711444  9.382808 13.05653  9.555321  9.912229 116.9166   100
```

And comparing the sole generation of integer partitions with `funPartition` above (no conversion to matrices), we have:

```
microbenchmark(nextPs = funPartition(10^4),
               algos = comboGeneral(0:100,25,TRUE,"sum","==",100,10^4))
Unit: milliseconds
  expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
nextPs 317.778757 334.35560 351.68058 343.81085 355.03575 521.13181   100
 algos   9.438661  10.12685  10.60887  10.37617  10.85003  13.99447   100
```

And to test equality:

```
identical(t(apply(funPartition(10^4), 2, rev)),
          comboGeneral(0:100,25,TRUE,"sum","==",100,10^4))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @BenBolker, you have no idea how much that means coming from you!!! Huge appreciation for all of your contributions and willingness to help.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for you explanations and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to generate a single target matrix -- probably not the most efficient way, and you'll only get *all* of the possible combos if you run a very large number of times. You can just use `lapply()` over `rep(5, num)` as below to generate `num` of them.

```
norm100 <- function(n=5){

  # generate some random values 
  vec <- sample(0:100, size=n^2)

  # put them in a matrix, normalizing to 100 and rounding 
  mat <- matrix(round((vec / sum(vec)) * 100), nrow=n)

  # find out how much the rounding makes us deviate from 100 
  off_by <- sum(mat) - 100 

  # get a random matrix element index 
  modify_idx <- sample(length(mat), 1)

  # if adjusting by `off_by` would put us out of the target interval, try again 
  while ((mat[modify_idx] - off_by) < 0 | (mat[modify_idx] - off_by) > 100){
    modify_idx <- sample(length(mat), 1)
  } 

  # once we have one (usually on the first shot), adjust so that mat sums to 100
  mat[modify_idx] <- mat[modify_idx] - off_by
  return(mat)
}

runs <- 1000
matrices <- lapply(rep(5, runs), norm100)
```

I haven't gotten any duplicates even after a few runs of 100,000, but if you do, you can always just toss the dupes.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an ordered way to do this, and not by randomly generating matrices, but I guess is the best option due there is no other way.

Comment: yeah I suspect there's a mathematical solution but don't know what it is without doing some work. Is the nature of the problem such that you *definitely* need every possible matrix?

Comment: Nice answer... I was wondering if there was some way to guarantee there wouldn't be duplicates.  I searched around and found something that could be useful [How to resample in R without repeating permutations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/24300).

Comment: interesting -- i think in this case theres so many possible matrices that you can just filter out dupes by calling unique() on the matrix list. that said, i did a few runs of 100k and didnt see a single dupe :p